# Factor of a dual curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-space, duality-theorems

Suppose that for a homogeneous polynomial $f(x,y,z)$ we have $f(x,y,z)=g(x,y,z) \cdot h(x,y,z)$. Assume $f_d$ and $g_d$ are the dual curves of $f$ and $g$ respectively. Is it true that $g_d$ is a factor of $f_d$?

My guess is that it is, since if a point $(X,Y,Z)$ is in the dual curve of $g$, then it must satisfy $(X,Y,Z)= \mu \nabla g(p,q,r)$ for some point $(p,q,r)$ such that $g(p,q,r)=0$ and some constant $\mu$. But then, $(X,Y,Z)$ also satisfies $(X,Y,Z)= \lambda \nabla f(p,q,r)$, since
$$
\nabla f(p,q,r)= g(p,q,r) \nabla h(p,q,r) + h(p,q,r) \nabla g(p,q,r) = h(p,q,r) \nabla g(p,q,r) 
$$
and hence $(X,Y,Z)$ is a multiple of $\nabla f(p,q,r)$ (as long as $h(p,q,r)\neq 0$, which I think we can always assume). Is this correct?

Comment: What does it mean that one set is a factor of another set? Just the simple subset relation?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I would think that OP means the defining polynomials, not the curves themselves.

Comment: @TabesBridges : And the (minimal) polynomial defining the larger set is the LCM of the polynomials of the subsets, ...

Comment: @LutzLehmann I meant that the polynomial defining one curve is a factor of the polynomial defining the other curve. I am sorry if I wasn't clear.